# Find all points at which the direction of steepest ascent of a function is in a given direction.

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

How do I find all the points at which the direction of steepest ascent of the function

$f(x,y)$=$x^2+y^2-2x-4y$

is in the direction $(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}))$

Comment: Find the gradient and then solve the differential equations

Comment: I have found the gradient vector but how do i find the differential equations to solve?

Comment: Oh wait, I thought it wanted the *curve* of steepest ascent.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient vector is
$$\nabla f(x,y)=(2x-2,\,2y-4)\ .$$
A basic property of the gradient is that this is the direction of steepest ascent from $(x,y)$, so you need it to be a positive constant times $(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2})$.  See if you can finish this.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the question now.